# I cannot install specific Node Modules [ejs]

Tags: javascript, node.js, ejs

To learn node.js I want to build a simple Website. For this I want to use ejs. However the installtion of ejs always fails. I tried this on multiple machines with different approaches.
Using Webstorms Built-in method in the settings for npm and using Plesk on a webserver I get the following error:

```
npm WARN lifecycle npm is using /opt/plesk/node/12/bin/node but there is no node binary in the current PATH. Use the `--scripts-prepend-node-path` option to include the path for the node binary npm was executed with.
sh: node: command not found
npm WARN bootstrap@4.4.1 requires a peer of jquery@1.9.1 - 3 but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.
npm WARN bootstrap@4.4.1 requires a peer of popper.js@^1.16.0 but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.
npm WARN project@1.0.0 No description
npm WARN project@1.0.0 No repository field.
npm ERR! file sh
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno ENOENT
npm ERR! syscall spawn
npm ERR! ejs@3.1.2 postinstall: `node --harmony ./postinstall.js`
npm ERR! spawn ENOENT
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Failed at the ejs@3.1.2 postinstall script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.
```

Webstorm gives me a very similar error on my local machine. Any other npm package I tried works fine. I installed express, bootstrap, jquery etc. The problem seems to be only with ejs.

My package.json looks like:

```
{
  "name": "project",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1"
  },
  "keywords": [],
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "dependencies": {
    "bootstrap": "^4.4.1",
    "express": "^4.17.1",
    "morgan": "^1.10.0"
  }
}
```

Any suggestions? One problem is aswell that I can only what Plesk is offering me on my webserver as I do not have the rights to run node or npm as a normal user.

Comment: Delete node_module and then  `npm install` I think may help you.

Comment: This sadly didn't help me. I have the same error

Comment: Show us your package dependencies. What you have installed so far.

Comment: I added the package.json, if it is what you mean.

Comment: I recommend using [yarn](https://yarnpkg.com/) as a node package manager. [Adding peer dependencies](https://classic.yarnpkg.com/en/docs/managing-dependencies/) with it is a lot simpler in my experience. Also if you're gonna use npm, ensure you have the latest version installed. Sometimes that's an issue. There's a [plugin for npm](https://www.npmjs.com/package/install-peers) that makes dependency installs simpler too (although I haven't used the plugin so I can't verify that statement)

Comment: You have successfully installed bootstrap, express and morgan. Ejs is not installed, try to install it by this command:  `npm i ejs` .

Comment: @ChrizZlyBear by the way, why are using such an old version of jquery with the newest version of bootstrap? There could be issues there..

Comment: I didn't use any version of jQuery. I deleted node_modules and added only ejs in my package.json. I get the same error (except the bootstrap warning is gone)

Comment: @RachelGallen I sadly cannot use yarn as the webhosting provider uses plesk and only supports npm

Comment: @SamimHakimi I did. Thats the error message I got.

Comment: @ChrizZlyBear well then look at that npm plugin, and definitely add jquery; one of your error messages is that you are missing it (for bootstrap)

Comment: @RachelGallen I removed bootstrap and jquery completly right now, as it is not needed and I want to use only whats needed for ejs right now.
What do you mean by "then look at that npm plugin"?

Comment: @ChrizZlyBear I posted a link to a plugin for npm, a package that you can install to handle peer dependencies. Just install it using npm. Follow the link to see install instructions. https://www.npmjs.com/package/install-peers

Comment: The problem with this package is that I cannot install any node modules outside of Plesks NPM install function.

Comment: @ChrizZlyBear A note: in future can you remember to tag users when you reply to comments (using the '@' symbol ; otherwise we don't get notified that you have responded to our comments. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
npm WARN lifecycle npm is using /opt/plesk/node/12/bin/node but there is no node binary in the current PATH. Use the `--scripts-prepend-node-path` option to include the path for the node binary npm was executed with.
sh: node: command not found
```

This error describes the solution when using plesk, which you're using?  Also see

https://support.plesk.com/hc/en-us/articles/360000644114-Node-js-Run-Script-option-doesn-t-work-no-node-binary-in-the-current-PATH

Comment: This is it! Thank you. This helped to fix the issue on my local windows machine (non Plesk) aswell. Just creating a .npmrc file in the root folder of the project and add "scripts-prepend-node-path=true" to it.